# Image goes off screen when decreasing screen width

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a header image when decreasing the width of the screen, disappears more and more instead of adapting to the screen:

[image]

When decreasing screen width more:

[image]

I thought that setting max-width: 100% should do it:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .header-media {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Maybe because the image has already its width set to 100%?
How can I force the image to be complete visible and never go off the screen?
Thanks

Comment: Hard to say what's going on with just some screenshots and a couple of CSS rules. If you can please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help.

Comment: @cabrerahector thanks I'm not sure what I can share more to make it reproducible, I scanned the whole CSS file (obviously I cannot share the whole long file), and the only property relevant to .header-media is position:relative

Comment: We need the CSS and HTML in your question that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @j08691 thanks I already answered it here

Answer (score 0):

```
object-fit: unset
```

That did the trick